# .xsl script added to .xml via .bat

Tags: xml, batch-file, xslt

I have file with a .tlf extension, file contains xml data, when I rename it with .xml, and it displays and reads as an xml file; 
I just use a .bat file with

```
ren FISDB001.tlf FISDB001.xml
```

Top lines of FISDB001.xml read as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspace id="ais:-24ivtsesb18hr-1f4r7b5s7n7c4" name="FISDB" path="NAVY" time="1481644548" workspace-type="AIS" version="1">
<object id="8#83067">
```

When I add .xsl script (line two), it displays in an internet browser (i.e. Google).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" version="2" href="FISDB.xsl"?>
<workspace id="ais:-24ivtsesb18hr-1f4r7b5s7n7c4" name="FISDB" path="NAVY" time="1481644548" workspace-type="AIS" version="1">
<object id="8#83067"
```

How can I add the .xsl script line via a .bat file?.

Also would I have to run two .bat files or could I have both processes done from one?.

Comment: If you want to add a processing instruction to an XML document then look into shells providing access to XML APIs; I don't think batch files provide that, so on Windows I would consider Powershell or Windows Script Host.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - you read my mind! I just answered with a PowerShell script!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q41654708.xml"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\q41654708.xml"
SET "xslline=^<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" version="2" href="FISDB.xsl"?^>"
(
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
  ECHO(%%a
  IF DEFINED xslline ECHO(%xslline%
  SET "xslline="
 )
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.
I used a file named `q41654708.xml` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Note that I used two different directories and the same filename. The output absolute filename should be different from the input

Simply `set` a variable to the required extra line - note that redirectors `<>` need to be escaped with caret `^`.

Then read each line and regurgitate it. After each line, spit out the required extra line, but then set the variable to *nothing*. This will ensure that the variable is empty for each line after the very first, inserting the required line in the required place.

Comment: Thanks a million Magoo.

Comment: Magoo, can I add the below lines to the .bat file to kill the FISDB.tlf? After it has created my FISDB.xml?

cd "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
DEL FISDB001.tlf 

I can run the lines in a separate .bat (and it works), but I'd like it all in one package (if possible).

Comment: No reason why not. Just put those lines before the `goto :eof`

Comment: Magoo, I added the lines and they work no problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Consider directly running your XSLT to transform the `.tlf` to `.html` without needing to call `<?xml-stylesheet ... ?>` inline. If you have your own XSLT processor (Xalan, Saxon, etc.) call in batch. Below uses an external PowerShell script for the transformation using the built-in .NET class, [XslCompiledTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx):

**PowerShell**

```bsh
param ($xml, $xsl, $output)

if (-not $xml -or -not $xsl -or -not $output) {
    Write-Host "& .\xslt.ps1 [-xml] xml-input [-xsl] xsl-input [-output] transform-output"
    exit;
}

trap [Exception]{
    Write-Host $_.Exception;
}

$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;

$xslt.Load($xsl);
$xslt.Transform($xml, $output);

Write-Host "generated" $output;
```

**Batch** *(of course change to relative directories as needed)*

```dos
Powershell.exe -File "C:\Path\To\PowerShell\Script.ps1"^
 "C:\Path\To\PowerShell\FISDB001.tlf" "C:\Path\To\PowerShell\FISDB.xsl"^
 "C:\Path\To\PowerShell\FISDB001.html"
```